# Can we run talend jobs with hangfire

Tags: c#, talend, hangfire

I will need to copy some data from database1 to database2. I'll use talend to perform the copy but i wonder if i can use hangfire to planned (run the job daily) my talend jobs (or may be SSIS)

Is this possible ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: Yes I want to do something like this : `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
    Cron.Daily);` but not use `Console.WriteLine` I want to use external job

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with hangfire, but a quick search shows it to be windows-specific; so I'm guessing it can run .bat files. So you can plan the job launcher (*.bat) obtained by building your job from the studio.

Comment: Hangfire has a `.NETStandard 1.3` version in it's NuGet package so it can run on any platform that can run .NET core (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Comment: Thanks for the info Scott!